# How can i dynamically compare and switch between two properties in JavaFX .bind call

Tags: javafx

I want to dynamically bind to the property with the lesser out of two value, so i can "fit" the circle into the bbox.
Ideally i hoped there is method like min or max for properties (hypothetical example below), but there is none as far as i looked. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

```java
this.outline.radiusProperty().bind(this.heightProperty().divide(2.).min(this.widthProperty().divide(2.)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "high-level" [Bindings API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html) has a [`Bindings.min(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#min(javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue,javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue)) method:

```
this.outline.radiusProperty().bind(Bindings.min(
    this.heightProperty().divide(2.), 
    this.widthProperty().divide(2.)
));
```